# Spring Integration AWS Kinesis Message Hanlder

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

The KinesisMessageHandler class accepts a constructor with input as AmazonKinesisAsync. AmazonKinesisAsync is an interface for accessing Kinesis asynchronously. Does this mean that there is no synchronous support for KinesisMessageHandler?

Also, what is the relevance of setSync method in KinesisMessageHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AmazonKinesisAsync` is really just rely on a Java's `Future` which could be turned easily to sync, blocking behavior via its `get()` method. That's what is that `setSync()` on the `KinesisMessageHandler` states for. Having `AmazonKinesisAsync` as an input does not mean that we cannot do sync operations. If we would have opposite for `AmazonKinesis` contract, we would not be able to perform async operations.

Comment: Git it ..that makes sense..thank you